# Handling invalid Firebase data with SWIFT Clean Architecture

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, clean-architecture

I am trying to show a list of messages received from Firebase using the Clean Architecture for Swift described here:

http://clean-swift.com/clean-swift-ios-architecture/

My doubt is how to handle when a data is invalid in firebase. Currently the app crashes as the index provided to UITableView is incorrect.

I am using a SWIFT version of the [FUArray class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI/FUIArray.m) (called as FireBaseQueryDataSource) which provides the index for the firebase nodes correctly, as follows

```
private func insertSnapshot(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot, previousChildKey: String?) {
    var index = 0
    if let previousChildKey = previousChildKey {
        index = self.index(key: previousChildKey) + 1
    }

    self.snapshots.insert(snapshot, at: index)
    self.delegate?.dataSourceDidAddObjectAtIndex(dataSource: self, snapshot: snapshot, index: index)
}
```

So these indexes are propagated to the UITableView as it can be appreciated from the following trace:

> ChatMessagesViewController.displayMessage(viewModel : ChatMessageViewModel) -> () (ChatMessagesViewController.swift:83)
>
> ChatMessagesPresenter.presentChatMessage(response : ObserveChatMessagesResponse) -> () (ChatMessagesPresenter.swift:36)
>
> ChatMessagesInteractor.chatMessagesWorkerDidAddObjectAtIndex(worker : ChatMessagesWorker, message : FireBaseChatMessage, index : Int) -> () (ChatMessagesInteractor.swift:66)
>
> ChatMessagesWorker.dataSourceDidAddObjectAtIndex(dataSource : FireBaseQueryDataSource, snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot, index : Int) -> () (ChatMessagesWorker.swift:131)
>
> FireBaseQueryDataSource.insertSnapshot(snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot, previousChildKey : String?) -> () (FireBaseQueryDataSource.swift:99)
>
> FireBaseQueryDataSource.(observeQuery() -> ()).(closure #1) (FireBaseQueryDataSource.swift:69)

When FIRDataSnapshot is parsed to FireBaseChatMessage in the Worker class the invalid data is detected so it is not propagated anymore.

```
 func dataSourceDidAddObjectAtIndex(dataSource: FireBaseQueryDataSource, snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot, index: Int) {
    if let message = FireBaseChatMessage(snapshot: snapshot) {
        self.output?.chatMessagesWorkerDidAddObjectAtIndex(worker: self, message: message, index: index)
    }
}
```

The thing is that following objects are with incorrect indexes so UITableView assertionhandler raises an exception.

I am not sure where and how should I handle the indices.  Interactor/Worker class does not have a reference to the list of nodes, so that I can't get fresh index there.

In FireBaseQueryDataSource class I can't put any logic related to this functionality as it can handle any kind of data.

Presenter or ViewController classes should not handle any logic, ChatMessageViewModel should have already the correct indexes when they arrive to that point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about propagating the invalid error at the specified index? that way you can delete it on the view part and the indices stay coherent.

Comment: Thank you Mijail, I think it is a possible solution. It would be completely feasible that on view level we decide to show one data or other. 

But I have the doubt that it wouldn't be actually business logic on the View level, which probably shouldn't happen. 

I guess this depends on how business logic is defined.

Anyway, finally I decided to disregard the error, don't propagate invalid data, discard given message in worker and recount indexes on view level based on timestamp values instead of relying on the indexes received from firebase.

I accept your solution still. Thanks